# Vundo/VirtuMonde detection application?

Tags: virus

I think a netbook I'm tasked with getting back into shape might have the Vundo/Virtumonde virus. I've run MS Security Essentials, Malwarebytes and Spybot but it's not spotting it.

I know this is a hard one to detect (and harder to remove). Before I go through the hassle of ordering system restore CDs (or just putting Ubuntu on this thing and being done with it) I wanted to be sure it, indeed, has this virus. Is there a spyware/anti-virus/malware app that is known to be able to detect the Vundo virus?

Comment: the netbook doesn't have a recovery partition?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [VundoFix](http://vundofix.atribune.org/) in the past. The UI isn't all that great, but it does it's job very well.

> VundoFix is a freeware removal tool
>   for many of the known variants of
>   Trojan.Vundo, Trojan.Conhook and other
>   similar infections.
>
> I've been working on this tool for
>   nearly 2 years constantly updating and
>   improving the way it detects and
>   removes the vundo infection.
>
> Generally an updated version is
>   released once a week and in some
>   special cases sometimes 2 or 3 times
>   in a week. The tool has had great
>   success removing the infection from
>   over 1 million computers to date and I
>   hope to continue with that same
>   success into the future.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC [combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix) seems to do a good job removing it. I'd also give a few livecd AV apps a try using unetbootin